How would someone go about calculating the temperature change of a reaction using the enthalpies of reactants an products in python using thermo lib?
I am designing software which calculates the stoichiometric combustion temperatures of different rocket fuel and oxidizer combinations. I've been using a specific method to find out the temperature of the reaction. It goes as follows:

First, balance the equation (I am going to use the example of Hydrogen and Oxygen)
Second, calculate the total enthalpy of the reactants
Then, calculate the enthalpy of the products at 298.15 K   [when H-H (Tr) = 0]
Iterate every temperature until Hp = Hr
Remove 273.15 to reach the temperature in degrees Celcius

I am doing this using values imported from the "thermo" Python library. However, I am encountering a strange problem, that is, it works for every propellant combination except the ones using Fluorine as an oxidizer. It even works with Difluorine Dioxide. So it gets me wondering, I there any other method I could use to calculate the reaction temperature of such reactions, do I even need another way of calculating it or is it just my code and/or chemical equations?
Below is a list of my equations for fluorine reactions before them being balanced:

H2 + F2 = HF
CH4 + F2 = CF4 + HF
C2H5OH + F2 = CF4 + H2O + HF
C6H5NH2 + F2 = CF4 + N2 + HF
NH3 + F2 = HF + NF3
C2H8N2 + F2 = CF4 + HF + N2
CH6N2 + F2 = HF + NF3 + CF4
N2H4 + F2 = NF3 + HF
CH3OH + F2 = CF4 + CO2 + HF
C12H26 + F2 = CF4 + HF

and here is the code I am using:
from thermo import ChemicalConstantsPackage, PRMIX, CEOSLiquid, CEOSGas, FlashPureVLS
import cantera as ct
from EqtnBalancer import solver

def split(txt, sep):
    return txt.split(sep)
def equationizer(equation):
    splitted = split(equation, "=")

    lhs = splitted[0]
    reactants = split(lhs, "+")
    reactantA = reactants[0]
    rA_Exponent = split(reactantA,"|")[0]
    reactantA = split(reactantA,"|")[1]
    reactantB = reactants[1]
    rB_Exponent = split(reactantB,"|")[0]
    reactantB = split(reactantB,"|")[1]

    rhs = splitted[1]
    products = split(rhs, "+")
    prodExponents, prodList = [], []
    for i in products:
        stuff = split(i,"|")
        prodExponents.append(stuff[0])
        prodList.append(stuff[1])
    return [[reactantA, rA_Exponent], [reactantB, rB_Exponent]], [prodList, prodExponents]
def exponentF(oxid, fuel):
    Reactants, fuel_ListSample = [], []
    match oxid:
        case "O2 (Oxygen)":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH4 (Methane)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)",
                               "NH3 (Ammonia)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + O2 = H2O"),
                         solver("CH4 + O2 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + O2 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + O2 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C6H7N + O2 = CO2 + H2O + NO2"),
                         solver("NH3 + O2 = H2O + NO2"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + O2 = H2O + NO2 + CO2"),
                         solver("N2H4 + O2 = H2O + NO2"),
                         solver("CH3OH + O2 = H2O + CO2"),
                         solver("C12H26 + O2 = H2O + CO2")]
        case "F2 (Fluorine)":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH4 (Methane)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)",
                             "NH3 (Ammonia)", "C2H8N2 (UnsymmetricalDimethylHydrazine)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)",
                             "N2H4 (Hydrazine)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + F2 = HF"),
                         solver("CH4 + F2 = CF4 + HF"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + F2 = CF4 + H2O + HF"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + F2 = CF4 + H2O + HF"),
                         solver("C6H5NH2 + F2 = CF4 + N2 + HF"),
                         solver("NH3 + F2 = HF + NF3"),
                         solver("C2H8N2 + F2 = CF4 + HF + N2"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + F2 = HF + NF3 + CF4"),
                         solver("N2H4 + F2 = NF3 + HF"),
                         solver("CH3OH + F2 = CF4 + CO2 + HF"),
                         solver("C12H26 + F2 = CF4 + HF")]
        case "F2O2 (Perfluorine Peroxide)":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + F2O2 = HF + H2O"),
                         solver("CH3OH + F2O2 = H2O + CO2 + HF"),
                         solver("C12H26 + F2O2 = CO2 + HF + H2O")]
        case "O3 (Ozone)":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + O3 = H2O"),
                         solver("CH3OH + O3 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C12H26 + O3 = CO2 + H2O")]
        case "N2O4 (Nitrogen Tetroxide)":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)",
                             "75% CH6N2 + 25% N2H4 (UH-25)", "50% CH6N2 + 50% N2H4 (Aerosine-50)", "CH3OH (Methanol)",
                             "C2H8N2 (UnsymmetricalDimethylHydrazine)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)",
                               "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + N2O4 = N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C6H5NH2 + N2O4 = CO2 + H2O + N2"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("CH3OH + N2O4 = N2 + CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("NH3 + N2O4 = N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H8N2 + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("N2H4 + N2O4 = N2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C12H26 + N2O4 = CO2 + N2 + H2O")]
        case "H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) 95%" | "H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) 85%":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)",
                             "75% CH6N2 + 25% N2H4 (UH-25)", "50% CH6N2 + 50% N2H4 (Aerosine-50)", "CH3OH (Methanol)",
                             "C2H8N2 (UnsymmetricalDimethylHydrazine)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)",
                               "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + H2O2 = H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + H2O2 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + H2O2 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C6H5NH2 + H2O2 = CO2 + H2O + NO2"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + H2O2 = H2O + NO2 + CO2"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + H2O2 = H2O + NO2 + CO2"),
                         solver("CH3OH + H2O2 = CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H8N2 + H2O2 = CO2 + H2O + NO2"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + H2O2 = H2O + NO2 + CO2"),
                         solver("N2H4 + H2O2 = H2O + NO2"),
                         solver("C12H26 + H2O2 = H2O + CO2")]
        case "AK20F: 80% HNO3 + 20% N2O4 (Nitric Acid)" | "AK27P: 73% HNO3 + 27% N2O4 (Nitric Acid)":
            fuel_ListSample = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)",
                               "CH3OH (Methanol)"]
            Reactants = [solver("H2 + HNO3 = NO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("C2H5OH + HNO3 = NO2 + CO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("CH6N2 + HNO3 = CO2 + NO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("N2H4 + HNO3 = NO2 + H2O"),
                         solver("CH3OH + HNO3 = NO2 + CO2 + H2O")]
    reaction = equationizer(Reactants[fuel_ListSample.index(fuel)])
    return reaction
def calculateHr(prodA, prodB, prodC, prods, coefs, A):
    hp = []
    A1 = ['H2', 'O2', 'H2O', 'CO2', 'F2', 'F2O2', 'N2O4', 'H2O2', 'O3', 'HNO3', 'CH4', 'Ethanol', 'Aniline', 'Ammonia',
          '1,1-dimethylhydrazine', 'Methylhydrazine', 'Hydrazine', 'Methanol', 'C12H26', 'NO2', 'CF4', 'N2', 'HF',
          'Aniline', 'NF3']
    A2 = [0, 0, -241.826, 0, 0, 31.61, 10.9, -135.403, 141.744, -134.19, -74.518, -235.03, 86.81, -45.556, 48.3, 54.14,
          97.56, -200.92, -353.5, 34.071, -933.76, 0, -272.726, 86.81, -123]

    if A == 1:
        for t in range(0, len(prodA)):
            Hp = (float(coefs[2]) * (float(prodA[t]) + A2[A1.index(prods[0])]))
            hp.append(float(Hp))

    elif A == 2:
        for t in range(0, len(prodA)):
            Hp = (float(coefs[2]) * (float(prodA[t]) + A2[A1.index(prods[0])])) + (float(coefs[3]) * (float(prodB[t]) + A2[A1.index(prods[1])]))
            hp.append(float(Hp))

    else:
        for t in range(0, len(prodA)):
            Hp = (float(coefs[2]) * (float(prodA[t]) + A2[A1.index(prods[0])])) + (float(coefs[3]) * (float(prodB[t]) + A2[A1.index(prods[1])])) + (float(coefs[4]) * (float(prodC[t]) + A2[A1.index(prods[2])]))
            hp.append(float(Hp))

    return hp
def reaction_processing(reaction):
    A = len(reaction[1][0])
    Temps = [100, 200, 298.15, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800,
             1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600,
             3700, 3800, 3900, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4300, 4400, 4500, 4600, 4700, 4800, 4900, 5000, 5100, 5200, 5300, 5400,
             5500, 5600, 5700, 5800, 5900, 6000]
    A1 = ["H2", "O2", "H2O", "CO2", "F2", "F2O2", "N2O4", "H2O2", "O3", "HNO3", "CH4", "C2H5OH", "C6H5NH2", "NH3",
        "C2H8N2", "CH6N2", "N2H4", "CH3OH", "C12H26", "NO2", "CF4", "N2", "HF", "C6H7N"]
    A2 = [0, 0, -228.582, 0, 0, 31.61, 9.079, -136.106, 142.674, -134.306, -74.873, -277.5, 0, -45.898, 48.9, 94.6,
        95.353, -277.5, -350.9, 33.095, -393.522, -933.199, 0, -272.546, 86.81]

    if A == 1:
        reacA1 = reaction[0][0][0].strip(); reacAE = reaction[0][0][1].strip()
        reacB1 = reaction[0][1][0].strip(); reacBE = reaction[0][1][1].strip()

        prodA1 = reaction[1][0][0].strip(); prodAE = reaction[1][1][0].strip()

        coefs = [reacAE, reacBE, prodAE]

        enth_reacA = A2[A1.index(reacA1)]
        enth_reacB = A2[A1.index(reacB1)]
        enth_prodA = []
        for t_new in Temps:
            val = Enthaly_Calculator(t_new, prodA1)
            enth_prodA.append(val)

        return enth_reacA, enth_reacB, enth_prodA, [prodA1], coefs, A

    elif A == 2:
        reacA1 = reaction[0][0][0].strip(); reacAE = reaction[0][0][1].strip()
        reacB1 = reaction[0][1][0].strip(); reacBE = reaction[0][1][1].strip()

        prodA1 = reaction[1][0][0].strip(); prodAE = reaction[1][1][0].strip()
        prodB1 = reaction[1][0][1].strip(); prodBE = reaction[1][1][1].strip()

        coefs = [reacAE, reacBE, prodAE, prodBE]

        enth_reacA = A2[A1.index(reacA1)]
        enth_reacB = A2[A1.index(reacB1)]
        enth_prodA = []; enth_prodB = []

        for t_new in Temps:
            valA = Enthaly_Calculator(t_new, prodA1)
            valB = Enthaly_Calculator(t_new, prodB1)

            enth_prodA.append(valA)
            enth_prodB.append(valB)

        return enth_reacA, enth_reacB, enth_prodA, enth_prodB, [prodA1, prodB1], coefs, A

    else:
        reacA1 = reaction[0][0][0].strip(); reacAE = reaction[0][0][1].strip()
        reacB1 = reaction[0][1][0].strip(); reacBE = reaction[0][1][1].strip()

        prodA1 = reaction[1][0][0].strip(); prodAE = reaction[1][1][0].strip()
        prodB1 = reaction[1][0][1].strip(); prodBE = reaction[1][1][1].strip()
        prodC1 = reaction[1][0][2].strip(); prodCE = reaction[1][1][2].strip()

        coefs = [reacAE, reacBE, prodAE, prodBE, prodCE]

        enth_reacA = A2[A1.index(reacA1)]
        enth_reacB = A2[A1.index(reacB1)]
        enth_prodA = []; enth_prodB = []; enth_prodC = []

        for t_new in Temps:
            valA = Enthaly_Calculator(t_new, prodA1)
            valB = Enthaly_Calculator(t_new, prodB1)
            valC = Enthaly_Calculator(t_new, prodC1)

            enth_prodA.append(valA)
            enth_prodB.append(valB)
            enth_prodC.append(valC)

        return enth_reacA, enth_reacB, enth_prodA, enth_prodB, enth_prodC, [prodA1, prodB1, prodC1], coefs, A
def Enthaly_Calculator(t, species):
    STP = 298.15

    constants, correlations = ChemicalConstantsPackage.from_IDs([species])
    eos_kwargs = dict(Tcs=constants.Tcs, Pcs=constants.Pcs, omegas=constants.omegas)

    liquid = CEOSLiquid(PRMIX, HeatCapacityGases=correlations.HeatCapacityGases, eos_kwargs=eos_kwargs)
    gas = CEOSGas(PRMIX, HeatCapacityGases=correlations.HeatCapacityGases, eos_kwargs=eos_kwargs)

    flasher = FlashPureVLS(constants, correlations, gas=gas, liquids=[liquid], solids=[])
    h_298 = flasher.flash(T=STP, P=ct.one_atm).H()/1000
    h_T = flasher.flash(T=t, P=ct.one_atm).H()/1000
    HH_Tr = (h_T - h_298)
    return HH_Tr
def close(arr, target):
    """
    Find the two closest numbers in the array to the target number.

    Parameters:
    arr (list of int/float): The list of numbers to search through.
    target (int/float): The target number to find the closest numbers to.

    Returns:
    list of int/float: A list containing the closest smaller and larger numbers to the target.
    """
    # Sort the array to ensure numbers are in order
    arr.sort()

    # Initialize variables to hold the closest smaller and larger numbers
    smaller, larger = None, None

    # Iterate through the array to find the closest smaller and larger numbers
    for num in arr:
        if num < target:
            smaller = num
        elif num > target:
            larger = num
            break  # Exit loop once the first larger number is found

    if smaller is None or larger is None:
        raise IndexError(f"Index could not be dound within list, could not find {target} within {arr}")
    return [smaller, larger]
def calculate(oxidizer, fuel):
    To = 298.15

    reaction = exponentF(oxidizer, fuel)
    processed = reaction_processing(reaction)
    enth_reacA = processed[0]
    enth_reacB = processed[1]
    enth_prodA = list[float](processed[2])
    enth_prodB = list[float](processed[3])
    enth_prodC = list[float](processed[4])
    prods = processed[-3]
    coefs = processed[-2]
    A = processed[-1]

    Hr = ((float(coefs[0]) * float(enth_reacA)) + (float(coefs[1]) * float(enth_reacB)))
    Hp = calculateHr(enth_prodA, enth_prodB, enth_prodC, prods, coefs, A)

    try:
        min_max = close(Hp, Hr)

        minA = min_max[0]
        maxA = min_max[1]

        minB = Hp.index(minA)
        maxB = Hp.index(maxA)

        Temps = [0, 100, 200, 298.15, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800,
                 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600,
                 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4300, 4400, 4500, 4600, 4700, 4800, 4900, 5000, 5100, 5200, 5300, 5400,
                 5500, 5600, 5700, 5800, 5900, 6000]
        lower_temp = Temps[minB]
        upper_temp = Temps[maxB]
    except:
        print("Not Available")
        print(Hp)
        print(Hr)

    Tp = To + ((Hr - maxA) / (minA - maxA) * (float(upper_temp) - float(lower_temp)) + float(lower_temp))
    return Tp

oxids = ["O2 (Oxygen)", "F2 (Fluorine)", "F2O2 (Perfluorine Peroxide)", "N2O4 (Nitrogen Tetroxide)", "H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) 95%",
           "H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) 85%", "O3 (Ozone)", "AK20F: 80% HNO3 + 20% N2O4 (Nitric Acid)","AK27P: 73% HNO3 + 27% N2O4 (Nitric Acid)"]
for i in oxids:
    fuels = []
    if i == "O2 (Oxygen)":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH4 (Methane)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)",
                 "NH3 (Ammonia)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
    if i == "F2 (Fluorine)":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH4 (Methane)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)",
                 "NH3 (Ammonia)", "C2H8N2 (UnsymmetricalDimethylHydrazine)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)",
                 "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
    if i == "F2O2 (Perfluorine Peroxide)":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
    if i == "O3 (Ozone)":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
    if i == "N2O4 (Nitrogen Tetroxide)":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)", "75% CH6N2 + 25% N2H4 (UH-25)",
                 "50% CH6N2 + 50% N2H4 (Aerosine-50)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C2H8N2 (UnsymmetricalDimethylHydrazine)", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)",
                 "N2H4 (Hydrazine)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
    if i == "H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) 95%" or i == "H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) 85%":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 75%", "C6H5NH2 (Aniline)", "75% CH6N2 + 25% N2H4 (UH-25)",
                 "50% CH6N2 + 50% N2H4 (Aerosine-50)", "CH3OH (Methanol)", "C2H8N2 (UnsymmetricalDimethylHydrazine)",
                 "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)", "C12H26 (n-Dodecane)"]
    if i == "AK20F: 80% HNO3 + 20% N2O4 (Nitric Acid)" or i == "AK27P: 73% HNO3 + 27% N2O4 (Nitric Acid)":
        fuels = ["H2 (Hydrogen)", "C2H5OH(Ethanol) 95%", "CH6N2 (MonomethylHydrazine)", "N2H4 (Hydrazine)", "CH3OH (Methanol)"]

    for k in fuels:
        Oxidizer = i; Fuel = k
        print(f"Combustion Temperature of {Fuel} & {Oxidizer} =", end =" ")
        result = calculate(Oxidizer, Fuel)
        strz = f"{round(result, 3)}K"
        print(strz)
    print()


Surely there is no specific temperature of a reaction? It can occur at any environmental temperature.

@lastchange what i mean by that is the increase in temperature caused by the excess energy of an exothermic reaction
